# Problem with image 'rotations' within a div element

Tags: javascript

I'm using the code below to create a 'rotation' of images for display on a website.  I wish for the images to display within a 'div' element...and i'm having trouble accomplishing that.  It seems the problem is when I attempt to set each image as the 'background image' for the element (the line that reads "document.getElementById("rotation").style.backgroundImage = "url(toString(ImgName[number]))";).  Only the initial image displays, without any 'rotation' of other images.  Any help appreciated, this is becoming very frustrating.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>test page</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<head>
<style>
div.rotation {
height: 256px;
width: 100%;
padding: 0px;
background-color: powderblue;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 5px;
border-radius: 25px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

 <div class="w3-quarter">
  <div class="w3-padding-small">
   <div class="w3-center">
    <div class="rotation"> 
     <p>    
      <img src='images/rotation/LA_Panel.png' id='rotateImg0' alt='image rotation' />
      <img src='images/rotation/McCulloch_256.png' id='rotateImg1' style='display:none;' alt='image rotation'  />
      <img src='images/rotation/MO_Panel.png' id='rotateImg2' style='display:none;' alt='image rotation' />
      <img src='images/rotation/Rommel.png' id='rotateImg3' style='display:none;' alt='image rotation' />
     </p>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>

<script type='text/javascript'>
var rotation = function () {
var currentImage,
    images = [],
    ImgName = [],
    count,
    hideImages,
    showImage,
    fn;

    count = (function () {              
      // Figure out how many images we have on the rotation          
      var x = 0;
      while (document.getElementById('rotateImg' + (x + 1).toString())) {
        images[x] = document.getElementById('rotateImg' + x.toString());
        ImgName[x] = document.getElementById('rotateImg' + x.toString()).src;
        x++;
      }
      return images.length;
    })();

    hideImages = function () {
      // Hide all the images              
      for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        images[i].style.display = 'none';
      }
    };

    showImage = function (number) {
      document.getElementById("rotation").style.backgroundImage = "url(toString(ImgName[number]))"; 
      images[number].style.display = 'block';
    };

    fn = {};
    fn.setupRotation = function () {
      // Show the first image
      currentImage = 0;
      showImage(currentImage);

      // Start the rotation
      var interval = setInterval(rotation.advanceRotation, 4000);
    };

    fn.advanceRotation = function () {
      if (currentImage + 1 == count)
        currentImage = 0;
      else
        currentImage++;
        hideImages();
        showImage(currentImage);
    };

    return fn;
    } ();

    rotation.setupRotation();      
  </script>
```

Comment: What are you trying to call on the last line with `rotation.setupRotation()`? Such a thing doesn't exist in the code you posted. Same with `rotation.advanceRotation` when you set the interval. The two functions you create with those names only exist within the scope of the function. Seems like you might have better luck housing them separately and passing them the arguments they need. EDIT - it doesn't even look like you're calling the rotation function you've defined?

Comment: I'm also not convinced you can call toString like that within the url function, but someone might be able to correct me there. But I imagine it would be safer to determine that string first, then pass it in as part of a string literal.

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply.  I did not write the Javascript code...it was a contribution from another member.  It works perfectly fine, it only became non-functional when I attempted to add the images as 'backgrounds' within the 'div' element.

Comment: Yea I wasn't sure about that myself...calling 'toStrin' within the URL function...

Answer (score 0):

One thought might be to pluck off the first child and slam him to the end of the line.

```js
let images = document.querySelector('#images');

setInterval(() => {
  let el = images.removeChild(images.childNodes[0]);
  images.appendChild(el);
}, 1000);
```

```css
#images {
  font-size: 0;
}

.img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="images">
  <div class="img" style="background-color: red"></div>
  <div class="img" style="background-color: orange"></div>
  <div class="img" style="background-color: yellow"></div>
  <div class="img" style="background-color: green"></div>
  <div class="img" style="background-color: blue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the code.  I tried it out because I thought it was an elegant and short solution.  However for some reason I'm not seeing my images at all...only the 'div' container for <div images>

Comment: <style>
#images {
    height: 256px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: powderblue;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 5px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
.img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 256px;
  height: 256px;
}
</style>

Comment: <div class="w3-quarter">
        <div id="images"> 
         <p>    
          <class="img" img src='images/rotation/LA_Panel.png' id='rotateImg0' alt='image rotation' />
          <class="img" img src='images/rotation/McCulloch_256.png' id='rotateImg1' style='display:none;' alt='image rotation'  />
          <class="img" img src='images/rotation/MO_Panel.png' id='rotateImg2' style='display:none;' alt='image rotation' />
         </p>
        </div>
     </div>